# SLD does not work

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have a style.xml and I am using a TILEWMS. I call my style file:

```
layersRef[ key ] = new ol.layer.Tile({
                            name: lotes,
                            title: sic,
                            type: 'capa',
                            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                                url: 'http://' + ip + ':8080/geoserver/sic/wms',
                                params: {FORMAT: 'image/png',
                                    VERSION: '1.1.1',
                                    tiled: true,
                                    LAYERS: sic:lotes,
                                    STYLES: '',
                                     SLD: encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:8090/style.xml'),
                                },
                                serverType: 'geoserver'
                            }),
                            visible: visibleEst,
                            opacity: 0.5,
                        });
```

and my style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>sic:lotes</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>A gold polygon style</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>gold polygon</Title>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#0004ff
                            </CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer> 
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

and it does not work and I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, please provide more detail as what is not working and what have you attempted thus far?

Comment: SLD must be in some address that can be accessed through the web

Answer (score 2):

If your WMS is at `'http://' + ip + ':8080/geoserver/sic/wms'` then that machine is very unlikely to be able to access `'http://localhost:8090/style.xml'` as when that request arrives the GeoServer machine will think of itself as being local host.

So instead of localhost you will need to use a fully qualified domain name or real ip address, that can be reached by the machine at `ip`.